# Dynamic Mongoose Schema based on property

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following user schema (where all distinct properties of different user types are consolidated):

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  status: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  address: Object,
  email: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"], match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, 'is invalid'], index: true},
  organization: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization' }],
  phone: {type: Number, unique: true, required: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"]}, 
  role: String, 
  hash: String,
  salt: String,
  deliverySchedule:  [{type: String, required: true}]

}
```

"Common" Schema (what all user types share in common):

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  status: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"], match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, 'is invalid'], index: true},
  phone: {type: Number, unique: true, required: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"]}, 
  role: String, 
  hash: String,
  salt: String
}
```

Role = "Customer":

```
  address: [{type: Object, required: true}]
```

Role = "DeliveryMan":

```
      deliverySchedule:  [{type: String, required: true}]
      organization: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, 
ref: 'Organization' }],
```

Role = "Seller":

```
      organization: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, 
ref: 'Organization' }],
```

I would like to add (and REQUIRE if possible) some fields to the "common" schema based on the user's role. However, I want to store them in the same collection.

How can I add a method to my `models/Users.js` to add properties to the schema based on "user.role"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `require` [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) optional for each role dependent fields.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  status: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"], match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, 'is invalid'], index: true},
  phone: {type: Number, unique: true, required: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"]}, 
  role: {type: String, enum: ['Customer', 'DeliveryMan', 'Seller'], required: true},
  address: {type: [Object],  required: isRequired("address")},
  deliverySchedule: {type: [String], required: isRequired("deliverySchedule")},
  organization: { type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Organization', required: isRequired("organization")},
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});

function isRequired(field){
    return function(){
        if(field == "address"){
            return this.role === "Customer"
        }
        else if(field == "deliverySchedule"){
            return this.role === "DeliveryMan"
        }
        else if(field == "organization"){
            return this.role === "Seller" || this.role === "DeliveryMan"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is more elegant than using discriminators. Thank you so much

Comment: I want to refactor inline functions to one function. How do I do that? `function authorize(roles) {  roles.forEach(role =>if (role === this.role) return true else return false `}

Comment: for clarity, I meant to ask where can I place this function and how do I access it ?

Comment: You can certainly take the functions out but you can't merge them into one, because that one function will have no context to tell which field is calling it and which `required` should be set to true.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I keep getthing this.role as undefined. Can you show me the right practice of refactoring this? Thanks :)

Comment: Come to think of it, you can actually use one function for all checks using closure. Updated my answer.